# Chrome kiosk weird behavior - opens and closes the preview

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, iframe

I create a shortcut as the following to open my page in POS/kiosk mode.

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --kiosk --kiosk-printing http://mywebsite.com/testing.php
```

This works without any problem. The page is open in fullscreen mode as expected. 
Now I need to print a PDF into my default printer. With that said I created an iframe.

```
$(function()
{
   $('<iframe id="pdf-iframe"></iframe>').hide().appendTo('body');
});

$(document).on('click', '#btn-print-pdf', function()
{
   $("#pdf-iframe").attr('src', 'somefile.pdf');
   $("#pdf-iframe").get(0).contentWindow.print();
});
```

Everything works, however I'm facing a weird behavior with Chrome. Whenever the button is clicked, the preview dialog of the PDF is opened and then automatically closed.

Is any possibility to print silently without showing the preview dialog?

I have tried to also add the option `--disable-print-preview` to my shortcut but then the popup is shown and not closed..

Comment: Where is `.src` of `<iframe>` element set?

Comment: I think there is no option to hide the print preview in kiosk mode. --kiosk-printing is required print preview to be enabled to do the job (print the document as soon the print() command from js executed)